# Pass to map two elements of the list

Tags: haskell

As I know map function takes function foo() and list and apply function foo() to each element of the list.  In the other words the parameter of foo() is the current element of the list:

```
*Main> map (+ 1) [0, 0, 0, 0]
[1,1,1,1]
```

But what if I want to apply bar() to the list where bar() have two parameters.  In the first, simple example the are current and the next parameter of the list. Something like

```
bar current next
  | current > next = current * 2
  | otherwise = next -2

map bar [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

In the second, more complex example the bar() has two parameters: current element of the list and current+k element of the list. Something like:

```
bar shift current
  | current > next = current * 2
  | otherwise = next -2
  where next = <get current+shift element of the list>

map (bar 2) [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

How can I do this ?

p.s.

I am just want to rewrite this python code in Haskell:

```
    for i in range (w, self.k + 1):
        if vector[i] > v + vector[i - w]:
            result[i] = vector[i]
        else:
            result[i] = v + vector[i - w]
```

Comment: It's not common (nor useful) to use empty parens to denote a function in Haskell. Better put it something like this: "`map` function takes function `foo :: a->b` and list of `a`s and apply `foo` to each element". The type systems helps enormously when trying to express things in words, in particular for stuff that can't simply be expressed in procedural terms and "function is applied to...".

Comment: Also, in Haskell `()` is a value of type `()` (the only value of type `()` actually, excluding bottom). `f()` is the same as `f ()` which means apply the function `f` to the value `()`, so referring to functions in this way confuses things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zipWith` and `drop n`:

```
mapBar :: (Num a, Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> [a]
mapBar n list = zipWith bar list (drop n list)
```